# Python - Put string inside a list recursively up to n levels

Tags: python, list, nested

I am working on to write a Python function `nest(a, b)` that takes a value `a` and a number `b`. Then the value `a` is put inside a `list`, which is put in another list, and so on, up to n levels.

For example:

```
nest("foo", 3)
```

should return:

```
[[[["foo"]]]]
```

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Comment: This board is about helping you solve a specific question. Therefore you have to do some work on your own. A question like: I want xy can you program that for me usually takes a professional and therefore costs money ;)

Comment: I would imagine `nest("foo", 0)` should be `"foo"`, not `["foo"]`, which means `nest("foo", 3)` should be `[[["foo"]]]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this,

```
def nest(obj, depth):
    ret = obj
    for _ in range(depth):
        ret = [ret]
    return ret
```

Comment: That won't give the correct result, did you mean `ret = [ret]`?

Comment: Yes, I actually meant that. Sorry for that silly mistake

Comment: At least based on the example in the original question, you have an off-by-one error here; `nest(obj, 3)` will return `[[[obj]]]`, not `[[[[obj]]]]`. To match the OP, initialize `ret = [obj]` instead. However, I think this is a more reasonable interpretation, where `nest(obj, 0)` is a no-op instead of wrapping `obj` in a single list.

Comment: I have thought that `nest("foo", 0)` must be `"foo"`, not `["foo"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You may write a [*recursive function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function) to achieve this as:

```
def my_func(s, n):
    return [s] if n == 0 else [my_func(s, n-1)]
```

**Sample Run:**

```
>>> my_func('foo', 3)
[[[['foo']]]]
```

**Note:** There is a maximum recursive limit allowed for the Python interpreter stack. This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.

You can check this value using [`sys.getrecursionlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) function which as per the doc:

> Return the current value of the recursion limit, the maximum depth of
>   the Python interpreter stack. This limit prevents infinite recursion
>   from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python. It can be
>   set by [setrecursionlimit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit).

Comment: Even without the limit, recursion is a poor way to implement this in Python, requiring an unnecessary amount of memory and a lot of overhead for the additional function calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive solution, it pretty much comes naturally from the problem definition:

```
def nest(val, n):
  if n <= 0:
    return val
  else:
    return [ nest(val, n - 1) ]
```